# How to call a function with 2d array

Tags: java

I am trying to create a 2d array and then find the average of all the elements inside the array

```
 float[][] dArr = {
                      {1.0f,2.0f},
                      {2.0f,2.0f}
                    };
    System.out.println(average(dArr[2][2]));

    }
    static double average (float dArr[][]){
        double sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<dArr.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;i<dArr[i].length;j++)
             sum=+dArr[i][j];
        return sum/dArr.length;
    }
```

But an error says there incompatible types: `float cannot be converted to float[][]`

Comment: just `average(dArr)`

Comment: remove `[2][2]` from `dArr[2][2]`.

Comment: Follow the error message. `dArr[2][2]` is the element in the second row, second col (2.0f) but you want to pass in the array so just pass in `dArr` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really passing a 2d array to the function when you call
`System.out.println(average(dArr[2][2]));`

Instead, you're passing just 1 float, or at least you would, but the element on index [2][2] is out of bounds. So change your function call to
`System.out.println(average(dArr));`

and the array should be passed to the function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. 
dArr.length is only counting the number of rows in the array, not items. So you should create a counter in the loop to divide by, or use the product as suggested above.
Change the sum to += dArr[i][j]; using =+ doesn't work.
In your for loop you want to use ++i and ++j, not i++ and j++.
In your nested loop your were testing i instead of j.
Here is functional code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   float[][] dArr = {
       {1.0f, 2.0f},
       {2.0f, 2.0f}
   };
   System.out.println(average(dArr));
}

static double average (float dArr[][]){

    double sum = 0;
    double count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dArr.length; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < dArr[i].length; ++j){
            sum += dArr[i][j];
            count += 1;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
    return sum/count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing one value of the array, `dArr[2][2]` (which is out of bounds anyway; see below), to your function. You need to pass in the whole array to function `average`. Also, you need to change the method signature of the function:

```
float[][] dArr = {
                      {1.0f,2.0f},
                      {2.0f,2.0f}
                 };
System.out.println(average(dArr));

static double average (float[][] dArr){
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<dArr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;i<dArr[i].length;j++){
            sum=+dArr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum / (dArr.length * dArr[0].length);
}
```

You will notice that the change in the last line. To get the total number of elements in the array, we have to multiply the rows by the column. `dArr.length` gives us the number of rows, while `dArr[0].length` gives the number of columns in the first row, which is the same for every row.

Also note that **arrays in java are zero-indexed**. As such the last element in your array is indexed `[1][1]` not `[2][2]`. You got this right in your function body, so *kudos!*

Comment: Also, ```dArr.length``` is the number of rows in the array. You want to calculate the average of all the elements in it. So you will need to change that either.